# Is cloud functions a valid replacement/implementation of a distributed system?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system

I want to process a list of data parallelly; processing of each element of the data won't affect other.

With for example google pub/sub + cloud functions, I could achieve something scalable and parallel, which looks like a distributed system.

I have little knowledge about distributed programming, and it seems that it takes a lot of time to master.

So I would like to know is this a replacement or a valid implementation of distributed system?

Answer (score 1):

For the specific use case you're talking about - dividing work among function invocations to run in parallel - yes, it sounds like that would be adequate.

I would be very hesitant to call it a full "distributed system" (at least not without your very strict definition of what that really is).  If you take wikipedeia's explanation of [distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing), you might have a very basic system in place, but lack of a peer-to-peer direct messaging system probably makes it unsuitable for many of the listed applications you see on that page.

The bottom line I think you should really consider is if it satisfies the requirements of the problem at hand.  Whether or not it's a "distributed system" is mostly irrelevant - either it works or it doesn't for that use case.

Comment: Yes you're right. what's important is to get the work done! Many machine learning algorithms require parallel computation (maybe not very similar to those listed on the wiki page). Just wondering if this a good idea to implement those algorithms on the cloud, by combine many pub/sub queue and many cloud functions. (I/O may be affected by the internet?)

Comment: Anything that works is a good idea.  Anything that's optimized for your specific use case is a great idea.